# Given a collection of curves, find the differential equation associated with them

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is as follows:

$$
\text { 1) } y=\frac{\sec x}{c_{1}+c_{2} \tan x} \quad ; \quad \underline{\text { The Answer is  }}: y y^{\prime \prime}-2 y^{\prime 2}-y^{2}=0
$$

My main problem with this question is the long algebraic process. Is there any fast way to solve this question?

One possible way of solving this is to form a matrix involving *y'*, *y''*, and *y* and try to make a system of equations with that matrix. Then because the equation should have a non-zero answer, we set the determinant to zero.

This is algebraically time consuming and provides the possibility for mistakes.

Comment: Show your work (At least indicate  your idea about which method you use or where you stuck).

Comment: Frankly , Any solution would work . I just wanna know how to solve this question .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write it as $C_1+C_2 \tan x=\frac{\sec x}{y}$. D. W.r. t. $x$
to get $$C_2 \sec^2 x=\frac{y \sec x \tan x-\sec x ~~y'}{y^2}$$
$$C_2=\frac{y \sin x-y'\cos x }{y^2}$$
Again D.w.t. $x$, we get
$$0=\frac{y^2(y' \sin x +y \cos x-y'' \cos x+y' \sin x)-(y
 \sin x-y' \cos x)~2yy'}{y^4}$$
$$\implies \frac{\cos x(y^2-yy''+2y'^2)}{y^3}=0 \implies y^2-yy''+2y'^2=0$$

One should actually be thankful that one gets it by hand irrespective of the length of the calculation.

Answer (score 5):

One could observe that
$$
y^{-1}=c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x
$$
which is the general solution of the harmonic oscillator. Thus
$$
(y^{-1})''+(y^{-1})=0
$$
Now $(y^{-1})'=-y^{-2}y'$ and $(y^{-1})''=-y^{-2}y''+2y^{-3}y'^2$ so that inserting gives
$$
y^{-3}(-yy''+2y'^2+y^2)=0.
$$